# No graph displayed using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have written the following Javascript code to generate a column graph using Highcharts, but no graph is displayed. What is the problem here? I checked for syntax errors, but could not find any.

```
<div id="container1" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

function create_graph() {
    var xAxisLabels = ['A ', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
    var yAxisTitle = 'Average';
    var xAxisTitle = 'XTitle';
    var graphTitle= 'Title';
    var PValues = [1,2,3,4,5];
    var NValues = [1,3,4,5,7];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart ({
        chart: {
             height: 600,
             width: 1200,
             renderTo: container1,
             type: 'column'
             //reflow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: graphTitle
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: xAxisLabels
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: yAxisTitle
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Postives',
            data: PValues
        }, {
            name: 'Negatives',
            data: NValues
        }]
    });
}
create_graph();
```

Comment: Create chart after DOM is loaded, for example: `$(function() { create_graph(); });`.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine on my end:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container1" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function create_graph() {
        var xAxisLabels = ['A ', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
        var yAxisTitle = 'Average';
        var xAxisTitle = 'XTitle';
        var graphTitle= 'Title';
        var PValues = [1,2,3,4,5];
        var NValues = [1,3,4,5,7];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart ({
            chart: {
                 height: 600,
                 width: 1200,
                 renderTo: 'container1',
                 type: 'column'
                 //reflow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: graphTitle
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: xAxisLabels
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: yAxisTitle
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Postives',
                data: PValues
            }, {
                name: 'Negatives',
                data: NValues
            }]
        });
    }

    create_graph();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/0yLjuLo8/)